# Org capture template with org-store-link

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-link

I would like to create an `org-capture` template such  that when I select it with `org-capture` (which is mapped to `C-c c` for me), I want the capture template to ask me for the description and URL of a link, then insert that into a heading and use the entered data as the title of a second level heading.

```
* Bookmarks
  ** Captured Link
  ** Captured Link
  ** ..
```

So far I use this:

```lisp
("b" "Bookmark"
        entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "/refile.org") "Bookmarks")
        "* %?\n")
```

The problem is that I need to press `C-c l` manually. I would like the `org-store-link` function to be called automatically when I run the capture template.

Comment: `org-store-link` does not insert a link: it stores a link for later insertion by `org-inert-link`, so I'm not sure what you mean - can you clarify? Providing a detailed usage example would go a long way towards clarifying what you mean.

Comment: As NickD said, you should `org-store-link` and add `"%a"` to the org-capture template to get stored-link like `"* %a\n%?"`. For more detail, please refer to the doc of `org-capture-templates`.

Comment: And If you want to add bookmarks from the web browser, you can use org-protocol + org-capture like https://cestlaz.github.io/post/using-emacs-70-org-protocol/, https://emacstil.com/til/2021/11/09/firefox-org-capture/ or https://www.mediaonfire.com/blog/2017_07_21_org_protocol_firefox.html

Comment: @NickD When I select the capture template with `org-capture` which is mapped to `C-c c` for me, I want the capture template to ask me for the description and url of the link then insert that into a heading.

Comment: I edited your question to include that information. Please check it and fix any inaccuracies. It is far better to edit the question and add those details than to add them in a comment. The question needs to stand on its own.

Comment: NickD Thank you. I appreciate it. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
("b" "Bookmark"
        entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "/refile.org") "Bookmarks")
        "* [[%^{link-url}][%^{link-description}]]")
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for.